# NodeJS store session in cache memory best practice

Tags: node.js, express-session

I need to build an architecture for a SaaS system, which will be separated to a few lambda functions on the backend, and one of them is a sign in / sign up service, which should verify user credentials and in case of a success create a session and return it to a user using a session cookie.
First of all, I thought of using a server so I can achieve a single entry point to the backend and will forward the requests to the lambdas endpoints.

What I actually want to know is how should I do the authentication process and where should I create the session cookie.

I thought of using express-session, and I thought of an option to return from the sign in lambda I mentioned above the payload that I want to store in the session and actually create the entire session on the server (which is the application backend's single entry point).

Another thing I wanted to know is what should I do in case I don't want to save the session's data on a Redis or any external DB and use the server's cache memory to store it, because we are not planning to have a lot of traffic to the application in the near future, is it a good practice for production? if not, what do you think may be a good practice instead?

Attached is an image I took from draw.io to show an example of the process I thought of.

[![draw.io image][1]][1]


Thanks.

Comment: the link to the image doesn't work

Comment: so you are gonna have a server for auth operations and pass requests to corresponding lambdas? Is this a requirement for you or you are free to choose?

Comment: @AlikhanOitan Actually I'm free to choose, but the reason I chose it was because I wanted the frontend to work with a single API URL, let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: it's actually can be done without the server for singly entry point. You can use API Gateway and choose to call a lambda depending on the route. So for example you have url.com and you have user-lambda and payment-lambda. You can route to user-lambda on url.com/user/* and payment-lambda on url.com/payment/*

Comment: @AlikhanOitan Alright, lets say I'd do something like that, so which of the lambdas should be responsible to manage the sessions the way you explained?

Comment: Lambdas do not have a persistent memory. So in your case, I would go for an external service like AWS Cognito or any other alternative. If you can switch from lambda to a server, then you could use the memory, of course, however, it loses the point of using lambdas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not recommended to use "express-session" with cache memory i.e. the default storage option.

> Warning The default server-side session storage, MemoryStore, is
> purposely not designed for a production environment. It will leak
> memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process,
> and is meant for debugging and developing.

source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session

For a list of stores, click [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores)

---

It is not difficult to use session store, you just need to have the instance of database running on the server.

One of the simplest option is using MongoDB as session store. I mostly use "connect-mongo" to set MongoDB as session store.

Example:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true },
  store: connectMongo.create({ mongoUrl: "mongodb://Username:Password@localhost:27017/DatabaseName" })
}))
```